# HttpWebRequest limited number of outgoing requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, httpwebrequest

I have developed an application that creates some HttpWebRequest objects and tries subsequest GetResponses(). I have set up fiddler as a proxy.
the problem is I can see only 2 or 3 concurrent outgoing requests in fiddler.

I tried setting `System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` to 100 in code, and checked it at runtime using debugger and it was correctly set for HttpWebRequest objects.

then I tried to implement `BeginGetResponse()`, while still using `readStream.ReadToEnd()` in the callback method. but this didn't change anything.

I'm using this asp.net code on a 64bit windows 8 machine on IIS 8. does this make any difference?

Comment: Can you post the code?